# Raspbian Run python script from rc.local

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

- i want to start this code automatically when raspberry pi start.
- code file name 11.py
- 11.py is also executable chmod 755 11.py

## !/bin/env python < top of the 11.py is

```
     from picamera import PiCamera
        from time import sleep
            camera = PiCamera()
            camera.start_preview()
            sleep(10)
            camera.stop_preview()
```

rc.local is also executable chmod 755 rc.local
inside of the rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
sudo python /home/pi/Google\ Drive/11.py &
exit 0
```

but when the pi start code is not start :(

Comment: `sudo` can ask for password, scripts in `rc.local` can't ask.

Comment: so what can i do ?

Comment: first I would use ie. `date > /var/log/date.log` to check if bash script is executed. Then I would use full path for `python`. This bash script probably is run as `root` so it doesn't need `sudo` but it can use different environment and may need full paths. You can also use redirection to file to see error messages `/fullpath/python your_script.py 2>1 >/var/log/your_script.log &` (`2>1` should redirect error message to standard output, and `> filename` should redirect standard output to file)

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo date > /var/log/date.log
-bash: /var/log/date.log: Permission denied